# How to detect if SpelExpressionParser did not find a variable in a context

Tags: parsing, null, expression, spring-el

I have a simple Question, but I don't found anything in the web.

Here is an example:

```
SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
StandardEvaluationContext ctx = new StandardEvaluationContext();
ctx.setVariable("variable", "value");

Expression expression = parser.parseExpression("variable + temp");
expression.getValue(ctx); // returns "valuenull"
```

I just need to know which part of expression could not be resolved. (In this case "temp")

Something like:

```
List<String> variables = expression.getNotResolvedVariables(ctx);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your snippet throws an exception when I run it (not a `valuenull` I think you have meant `#variable + #temp` as the expression. Otherwise an exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'variable' cannot be found on null
```

As to your main question...

- there's no such a method in `Expression` to retrieve all variables or in a context to retrieve all unresolved variables for a given expression, but...
- you can visit the object representation (AST) of the Spring expression through [getAST() method on SpelExpression](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/expression/spel/standard/SpelExpression.html#getAST--) and collect all the `VariableReference`
- then compare the set of all references variables to the one defined in your current context